# How to move button to random position? (Swift) while iAd is showing

Tags: ios, swift

I have been doing it great with the answer in this question:

[Strange @IBAction conflict or bug? (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077229/strange-ibaction-conflict-or-bug-swift/26077845#26077845?newreg=ab786fad2e1b4beea1a24b13e885e018)

But since I put iAds, the random position stop working that well, now the button is showed sometimes at his real place in Main.storyboard and sometimes at a random place inside the screen, this is only when iAd is showing

here is the code:

```
var newButtonX: CGFloat?
var newButtonY: CGFloat?
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let buttonWidth = button.frame.width
    let buttonHeight = button.frame.height

    // Find the width and height of the enclosing view
    let viewWidth = button.superview!.bounds.width
    let viewHeight = button.superview!.bounds.height

    // Compute width and height of the area to contain the button's center
    let xwidth = viewWidth - buttonWidth
    let yheight = viewHeight - buttonHeight

    // Generate a random x and y offset
    let xoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))
    let yoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yheight)))

    // Offset the button's center by the random offsets.
    newButtonX = xoffset + buttonWidth / 2
    newButtonY = yoffset + buttonHeight / 2 
    circle.center.x = newButtonX!
    circle.center.y = newButtonY!
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if let buttonX = newButtonX {
        button.center.x = buttonX
    }
    if let buttonY = newButtonY {
        button.center.y = buttonY
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solve it, I use the iAd bannerview on the Main.storyboard and now it works fine